# How to create an if statement in database.yml to use different databases based on the current user in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

as i explained i want to use different databases based on the user.

I got a partner table created with devise and i have multiple databases that i created.Everyone of those databases have the same schema and same relationships.

What i want to accomplish is something like

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_ <%= current_partners%>

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_ <%= current_partners%>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db_ <%= current_partners%>
```

why can't i use this statement ??

Btw i m using mysql2 as seen in the code fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `database.yml`, just mention default database configuration. Whenever, you want to switch between databases, call user defined `switch_database` method to connect to another database before making hit to corresponding database. Something like:

```
def switch_database
  establish_connection (
    :adapter  => "mysql2",
    :host     => "another_host_name",
    :username => "username",
    :password => "password",
    :database => "db_#{current_partner}"
  )
end
```

Place above method in appropriate file as per your convenient to call it.

Answer (score 0):

`database.yml` is loaded on application boot, variables like `current_partners` are not available at this point as they are request specific. You need to create all the databases within your `database.yml` and then tell rails which one to use in your controller. This however may cause a lot of concurrency issues (not sure though, never actually did this - see below).

Note however that this is not considered the best practice. Why not to have `partners` models and then have an associations instead?

Comment: I do have a partners model.But i'll have huge tables and i want them be seperated for quicker and responsive queries.How can i use it?

Comment: Just index foreign_keys to partner models and all will be extremely quick.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout these gems which can help you achieve multi-tenancy in your Rails application [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Multitenancy).

[Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) is one of quite active and Rack based database multi-tenancy ruby gems. I hope it helps.